# Cannot create list in domain class

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, spring-boot

When I bootRun my application it runs without any problems.

However, when I add a List attribute to one of the domain classes, I get a lot of errors which I do not understand and the application does not run.

This is what I am trying to do

```
private List<Integer> mydata;
```

This is the class

```
package ...;

imports...

@Entity
@Table(name="property")
public class Property {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private Double price;

private String address1;

private String address2;

private String postCode;

private String description;

private Integer views;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="property", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
//Tried without the relationship annotation as well!
private List<Integer> mydata;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="property", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<PropertyImage> images;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="Property_id", referencedColumnName="id")


//getters and setters here
```

}

Is there something very obvious which I am missing?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the errors you are getting.

Comment: Can we see the entire class in which you're using it. Or the error message? This is very hard to solve otherwise ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot map a list of Integers like that. To do so, you have to use `@ElementCollection`. See [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e5405) for additional information.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "TableName", ....)
private List<Integer> mydata;
```

Comment: It worked, thank you!